# R How to slice a data.table according to a date into a list

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table like this

```
Date          Rain      Temp
1990-01-01    0.0       29.2
1990-03-03    0.0       30.4
1990-06-10    NA        25.2 
1990-09-02    0.3       26.8
1991-01-04    0.1       31.2
1991-03-02    0.0       34.0
1991-06-01    5.4       27.1 
1991-09-01    0.4       25.1
1992-01-09    0.0       30.8
1992-03-03    0.0       30.7
1992-06-03    4.6       23.1
1992-09-03    0.8       29.1
```

But bigger, lots of lines and sometimes the years have different numbers of rows. I need to slice it every time the year changes and save the result to a list:

```
[[1]]
    Date          Rain      Temp
    1990-01-01    0.0       29.2
    1990-03-03    0.0       30.4
    1990-06-10    NA        25.2 
    1990-09-02    0.3       26.8
[[2]]
    Date          Rain      Temp
    1991-01-04    0.1       31.2
    1991-03-02    0.0       34.0
    1991-06-01    5.4       27.1 
    1991-09-01    0.4       25.1
[[3]]
    Date          Rain      Temp
    1992-01-09    0.0       30.8
    1992-03-03    0.0       30.7
    1992-06-03    4.6       23.1
    1992-09-03    0.8       29.1
```

---

What I'm doing until now:

```
yearly.data <- list
dates.intervals <- list(c("1990-01-01","1990-12-31"),
                        c("1991-01-02","1991-12-31"),
                        c("1992-01-02","1992-12-31"))

for (y in dates.intervals){
    yearly.data <- c(yearly.data, list(data[Date %between% y]))
}
```

But this way, the result is

```
yearly.data
[[1]]
function (...)  .Primitive("list")

[[2]]
      Date          Rain      Temp
    1990-01-01    0.0       29.2
    1990-03-03    0.0       30.4
    1990-06-10    NA        25.2 
    1990-09-02    0.3       26.8
...
...
```

I can't take out that value from `[[1]]`, but this is not my main concern. My main concern is that I think there must be a much more efficient way to do this, but I can't find it.

Comment: `split(dat, substr(dat$Date, 1, 4))`. If the `Date` column is already of class `Date`, you could also do `split(dat, lubridate::year(dat$Date))`

Comment: @d.b `Date` is of class `Date` so I used your last suggestion and this is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: If you are using data.table, there's no need to also use lubridate here. Data.table comes with a year function (see `?year`) for its IDate class.

Answer (score 0):

The `split()` function can be used to split a data frame into multiple data frames in a list, given a factor variable. For example:

```
rawData <- "Date          Rain      Temp
1990-01-01    0.0       29.2
1990-03-03    0.0       30.4
1990-06-10    NA        25.2 
1990-09-02    0.3       26.8
1991-01-04    0.1       31.2
1991-03-02    0.0       34.0
1991-06-01    5.4       27.1 
1991-09-01    0.4       25.1
1992-01-09    0.0       30.8
1992-03-03    0.0       30.7
1992-06-03    4.6       23.1
1992-09-03    0.8       29.1"

data <- read.table(textConnection(rawData),header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data$year <-as.factor(substr(data$Date,1,4))

yearList <- split(data,data$year)
```

Note that I chose to read the date field as a character string and subset the first 4 characters rather than reading it as a date and then using `lubridate::year()` to extract the year.

regards,

Len